# Unable to run the thingsboard from premise minikube

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, minikube, thingsboard

I have followed the below link but I am getting the error as:

```
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne$ git clone https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-pe-k8s.git
```

```
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ cat .env

# Can be either basic (with single instance of Zookeeper, Kafka and Redis) or high-availability (with Zookeeper, Kafka and Redis in cluster modes).
# According to the deployment type corresponding kubernetes resources will be deployed (see content of the directories ./basic and ./high-availability for details).
DEPLOYMENT_TYPE=basic
PLATFORM=
# Database used by ThingsBoard, can be either postgres (PostgreSQL) or hybrid (PostgreSQL for entities database and Cassandra for timeseries database).
# According to the database type corresponding kubernetes resources will be deployed (see postgres.yml, cassandra.yml for details).
DATABASE=postgres
```

```
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ nano .env

# Can be either basic (with single instance of Zookeeper, Kafka and Redis) or high-availability (with Zookeeper, Kafka and Redis in cluster modes).
# According to the deployment type corresponding kubernetes resources will be deployed (see content of the directories ./basic and ./high-availability for details).
DEPLOYMENT_TYPE=basic
PLATFORM=minikiube
# Database used by ThingsBoard, can be either postgres (PostgreSQL) or hybrid (PostgreSQL for entities database and Cassandra for timeseries database).
# According to the database type corresponding kubernetes resources will be deployed (see postgres.yml, cassandra.yml for details).
DATABASE=postgres
```

```
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ ./k8s-install-tb.sh --loadDemo
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ kubectl delete deployment --all
deployment.apps "postgres" deleted
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ minikube delete
  Deleting "minikube" in virtualbox ...
  Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ minikube start
  minikube v1.15.1 on Ubuntu 16.04
✨  Automatically selected the virtualbox driver
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.19.4 on Docker 19.03.13 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ ./k8s-install-tb.sh --loadDemo
namespace/thingsboard created
Context "minikube" modified.
persistentvolumeclaim/tb-node-license-pv-claim created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/postgres created
service/tb-database created
configmap/tb-node-db-config created
Waiting for deployment "postgres" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
deployment "postgres" successfully rolled out
configmap/tb-node-config created
pod/tb-db-setup created
error: timed out waiting for the condition on pods/tb-db-setup
pod "tb-db-setup" deleted
```

How to successfully install and check in the browser as shown in the link below.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster/minikube-cluster-setup/

@PjoterS
I had missed to execute the Enable ingress addon and as you told me 'Check what addons you have enabled minikube addons list', I executed the below commands as in link https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster/minikube-cluster-setup/

Step 5. Running
Execute the following command to run installation:

```
$ ./k8s-install-tb.sh --loadDemo
```

Where:

--loadDemo - optional argument. Whether to load additional demo data.
Execute the following command to deploy third-party resources:

```
$ ./k8s-deploy-thirdparty.sh
```

Type ‘yes’ when prompted, if you are running ThingsBoard in high-availability DEPLOYMENT_TYPE for the first time or don’t have configured Redis cluster.

Execute the following command to deploy ThingsBoard resources:

```
$ ./k8s-deploy-resources.sh
```

After a while when all resources will be successfully started you can open http://{your-cluster-ip} in your browser (for ex. http://192.168.99.101). You can see your cluster IP using command:

```
$ minikube ip
```

You should see ThingsBoard login page.

and found:

```
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ minikube addons enable ingress
  Verifying ingress addon...
  The 'ingress' addon is enabled
k@krishna-Lenovo-G50-70:~/testExperimentsOne/thingsboard-pe-k8s$ ./k8s-install-tb.sh --loadDemo
namespace/thingsboard created
Context "minikube" modified.
persistentvolumeclaim/tb-node-license-pv-claim created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/postgres created
service/tb-database created
configmap/tb-node-db-config created
Waiting for deployment "postgres" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
deployment "postgres" successfully rolled out
configmap/tb-node-config created
pod/tb-db-setup created
error: timed out waiting for the condition on pods/tb-db-setup
pod "tb-db-setup" deleted
```

timed out error when executing this command $./k8s-install-tb.sh --loadDemo

Comment: Could you specify what errors you have? In first comment you are cloning rebo and in second you are checking `.env`. Later you start Minikube and it looks ok. Well as there is everything described, with what exactly you need help? In minikube you need to expose service to be reachable outside the cluster by using `LoadBalancer` or `NodePort` (in tutorial NodePort was used). Check what addons you have enabled `minikube addons list`

Comment: @PjoterS Please the the error - 'timed out waiting for the condition on pods/tb-db-setup' above.

Comment: Could you provide outpud of `kubectl get svc -A` and any additional information about `tb-db-setup` pod? `kubectl describe` or `kubectl logs` or `kubectl get events | grep tb-db-setup`?

Answer (score 0):

I see there is typo on your .env file output, the

> PLATFORM=minikiube

should be

> PLATFORM=minikube

(note the extra i in "kiube")